# What are some statistical principles that need to be applied to bucketing chart points by time?

Tags: data-visualization, mean

I am taking the average of points by time range.  There aren't an equal number of points per time bucket.  Is this an acurate representation when simplifying/minimizing points on a line chart?

i.e. 5-minute time spans would result in averaging 3 items and 2 as follows
    
17:00, 100
    
17:01, 200
    
17:04, 150
    
--------------
    
17:05, 100
    
17:09, 200

The reason for the reduction is the amount of data.  The density is higher than can be easily viewed on a line chart.  These integer values are percentages of a sensor level (0-100).

Comment: It all depends on what those "points" represent and how they were measured. Please edit this post to include this contextual information and also tell us *why* you are attempting to simplify the graphic.

Comment: @whuber good suggestion.  Appended.

Answer (score 2):

A principled statistical "bucketing" procedure for graphing tends to look not so much like an explicit bucketing procedure.  The general name for these generalized bucketing procedures is *scatterplot smoothers*, which operate on two dimensional data $\{(x_i, y_i)\}$ and produce a "smooth" representative curve.

Probably the closest to explicit bucketing is a *rectangular kernel density smoother* (it's a mouthful, I know).  This is a generalization of the *moving average* construction - we set an explicit window width $w$, and construct the smoothed data $\hat y(x)$ as an explicit average of the points that fall inside the window

$$ \hat y(x) = Avg(y_i \mid x - w < x_i < x + w) $$

Qualitatively, we construct a window around $x$ of width $w$, and average together all the $y$'s whose corresponding $x$'s lie inside this window.  As the window slides from left to right, some $x_i$'s will enter the window and others will fall out, changing the estimate $y(x)$.

The rectangular kernel density smoother produces a stair step looking smooth

[image]

Making the window thinner will fit closer to the data, and make the smooth more jagged

[image]

Making the window wider makes the smooth average over more of the data, and makes the smooth less jagged

[image]

The rectangular kernel always results in a stair step pattern, which is rather unappealing.  To get a true smooth curve, we need to avoid points dropping out and entering the window at discrete points in time.  To do this, we can use a *gaussian* window instead of a rectangle

$$ \hat y(x) = \sum_i \left( y_i e^{- \frac{(x_i - x)^2}{w} }\right) / \sum_i \left( e^{- \frac{(x_i - x)^2}{w} } \right) $$

This looks complicated, but is really just a weighted average.  We weight the $y_i$ with a gaussian that falls off rapidly away from the point $x$ at which we are calculating the smooth.  This results in a beautiful smooth curve

[image]

Again, making the width smaller fits closer to the data and results in a pointier smooth

[image]

and making it wider fits further from the data

[image]

The subject of scatterplot smoothing is one of my favorites.  It's very fun and results in some beautiful pictures.  A great introduction is chapter 2 of *Generalized Additive Models* by Hasite and Tibshirani, where you can read about even more exotic ways to "bucket" your data!